# My wordpress website being hacked with code eval($_SERVER['HTTP_81DB2B3']

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my website, I get information from wordfence about my WordPress website getting hacked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JySeL.png) add found a code `eval($_SERVER['HTTP_81DB2B3']` so i removed it but in a few second the code going back. someone, please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had something very similar to this. Go to your cPanel and search for "Cron Jobs" and scroll down to see if there's any malicious cronjobs setup. You might have some that look like `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(....` that are essentially causing this to reoccur. Not a complete fix to this issue, but you'll have to delete those cronjobs to ensure that that line of code doesn't keep reappearing. In addition to that, you'll also need to make sure those cronjobs don't show up again. Use a plugin like Wordfence (suggested above as well) to look for malicious files and if it helps replace your home directory (except for wp-content and wp-config) with fresh files.

Comment: I have been looking for days where the injected code came from. After reading this i did a "crontab -e -u www-data. Which showed the exact same thing as you mentioned above. This all happened after the recent security issue in the plugin contactform 7 as mentioned here. https://contactform7.com/2024/03/12/contact-form-7-592/#more-55733

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same hack on several websites.

It's quite a sophisticated attack because it always comes back due to the cron jobs.

Try to run the following code and see if it produces any output. If it does you gotta check what the code does. It might be a code that is adding those hacks again.

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('crontab -l');
?>
```

If you can see the cron jobs you most likely can remove them with the following code.

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('crontab -r');
?>
```

If the cronjobs come back, then there are other hacks or vulnerabilities still present.

Answer (score -2):

If your website got hacked then I guess more than 1 file was affected by it,

---

**case-1**: If you are able to access the Wordpress Backend In this case, if you are able to access the Wordpress backend then I suggest you

### Step-1: Add one plugin called (Wordfence Security – Firewall & Malware Scan
) and scan your website with it.

Step-2: After scanning the site remove all suspicious code from the site.

**Case 2**: If you are not able to access the Wordpress backend then you have to update your Wordpress manually with the hosting file manager or FTP.

---

Please Note: Please take a backup of your website before do any changes.

Comment: for case 1, I do all of the steps u suggest but the code back again bro, can't remove the code
and for case 2, actually i always update the WordPress version to a new version, now my WordPress version is 6.02, and my PHP version is 7.4

Comment: I suggest you update your wordpress Manually, after that please check the plugin directory vis the hosting file panel and check that you have any suspicious plugins have been added when your site has been hacked,

If any plugins have been added than delete it:

I will provide you a link ho can you update Wordpress manually?

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/ultimate-guide-to-upgrade-wordpress-for-beginners-infograph/

Comment: oke, thanks for you suggest Senil Kanani

Comment: look for malicious files being added to the root of your website/ inside wp-content and such. Remove them if you find anything. Try to put a clean version of wordpress (manually) and replace all files except for the folder "wp-content" that's the only folder you don't have to replace or you'll lose everything